# Shape picture goes to unexpected position, even with correct .top and .left values - Word VBA

Tags: vba, image, ms-word

The problem is, I'm creating a new shape picture to replace a previous one.
However, even tough the new shape properties Top and Left are exactly the same as the previous picture, the new shape gets dislocated. This happens on a header shape.
I believe there is some sort of hidden property I'm not able to find on VBA watch.

I'm adding the code as this (A simplified version):

```
For i = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Shapes.count To 1 Step -1

'shape to delete:
    set shp2del = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Shapes(i)
'shape to add
Set shp2 = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Shapes.AddPicture(replace_path, False, True, shp2del.Left, shp2del.Top, shp2del.width, shp2del.height)

shp2del.delete

next i
```

And voilá, it creates the object shp2, deletes shp2del.. with a small problem, in some documents, it doesn't stay in position.

I tried many things, redefining shp2.top and shp2.left after creating,
looked for relative positions properties, anchor object properties, compared with the shape to delete and new shape, and everything seems to be the same unless I'm (most likely) missing a property.

I also tried to create a macro and see the code that would change the new shape into position, but unfortunately while creating a macro word doesn't allow to handle pictures very well..

The only hint I found was this one, but to change this programmatically, I don't know how.

[image: old shape on left, new shape on right]
Update:

After the answer from m4o_tim the options that word displays are more accurate, still the distances remain incorrect on the final document

[image: old shape on left, new one on right]

I'm also curious about the lock anchor and allow overlap, but this is surely hidden within shp2.anchor and I'll try those out.

Regarding the absolute position I couldn't find a property that I could set. 
Thanks for the help m4o_tim, is there anyone else who can help?

Update 2:
Finally its working, basically what's needed to do is to re-define top and left positions after the settings

```
                        With newshp
                        .WrapFormat.Type = oldshp.WrapFormat.Type
                        .RelativeHorizontalPosition = oldshp.RelativeHorizontalPosition
                        .LeftRelative = oldshp.LeftRelative
                        .RelativeVerticalPosition = oldshp.RelativeVerticalPosition
                        .TopRelative = oldshp.TopRelative
                        .Top = oldshp.Top
                        .Left = oldshp.Left
                        .LockAnchor = oldshp.LockAnchor
                        End With
```

After this it was working perfectly. Thanks m4o_tim

Update 3:
I realized this luckily worked in only one section. The reason for such is the anchor position.

If I compare 
shp2del.Anchor.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
with 
shp2.Anchor.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)

I will get different values. I will open up a new question about this. Thanks everyone.

Comment: The Anchor property is a Range and identifies the paragraph in the header that the shape is anchored to. The Information property is giving information about that range not the shape. See the edited code in my answer below for setting the anchor.

Comment: But isn't the anchor a property of the shape? If so a property of that anchor, is also a property of the shape, right? Also, I believe the range is a sum of all the properties of the previous element, such as Anchor.Range, is a collection of all properties of Anchor. Am I wrong?

Comment: Regardless I tried that shp2del.anchor just 10 minutes after posting this, it's working as expected :) But I quite don't understand why the anchor.information couldn't be used to define exactly where i want the picture relatively to the page.

Comment: Yes the anchor is a property of the shape but only in that it refers to the paragraph the shape is anchored to. It is a separate object, with its own properties, but with a relationship to the shape. Information is a property of the range and is read only so can't be used to set anything. Also, as the wrap format of your picture isn’t "inline" its position can be different to the paragraph’s position, which is why you get different values.

Comment: Think of it like an apple on a tree. Two different, but related, objects each with their own properties. If you could plot their positions they would likely be different too.

Comment: And just as a tree can have numerous apples attached to it, a range can have multiple shapes anchored to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When adding your new shape you haven't specified the relative position so Word applies its default, relative to column and paragraph.

When you come across things in the Object Model that you are unfamiliar with try using the Object Browser and online help documentation.

Your code should be something like this:

**Edit:** Included setting anchor from old image

```
'shape to add
Set shp2 = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Shapes.AddPicture(replace_path, False, True, , , shp2del.width, shp2del.height, shp2del.Anchor)
With shp2
    .WrapFormat.Type = shp2del.WrapFormat.Type
    .RelativeHorizontalPosition = shp2del.RelativeHorizontalPosition
    .Left = shp2del.Left
    .RelativeVerticalPosition = shp2del.RelativeVerticalPosition
    .Top = shp2del.Top
End With
```

Comment: Thank you, it almost worked, but I think there's some scaling involved. The distances set are different.. I'll update the question with the new findings.